# Estou com um erro na stored procedure , provavelmente dentro do IF

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

A `procedure` deve inserir um cliente com pelo menos 10 caracteres no nome, uf(unidade federativa) com 2 caracteres e rena mensal maior de 500.00.

Segue a query:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_incluir_cliente(in xnome varchar(45), in 
xrenda_mensal decimal(10,2),in xuf varchar(2));
    BEGIN
        IF (len(xnome))>=10 THEN
            IF xrenda_mensal>=500.00 THEN
               IF (len(xuf)>=2 THEN
                   insert into cliente(nome,renda_mensal,uf) 
                       VALUES(xnome,xrenda_mensal,xuf);
               END IF;
            END IF;
        END IF;
END $$
```

Segue a resposta do **phpmyadmin** com a referência aos meus erros:

```
#1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a ';
BEGIN
    IF (len(xnome))>=10 THEN
        IF xrenda_mensal>=500.00 THEN
            ' na linha 1
```

obs: acredito que seja algo no `IF` no entanto como eu não soube resolver eu posso estar errado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que informar qual o banco de dados que você está usando, pois cada sistema tem suas particularidades.

Essa sintaxe está parecendo MySQL, por conta do `DELIMITER`, se for o problema é que entre `BEGIN` e o final da declaração dos parâmetros da procedure tem um ';'. Tire-o.

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_incluir_cliente(in xnome varchar(45), in 
xrenda_mensal decimal(10,2),in xuf varchar(2))
BEGIN
        IF (len(xnome))>=10 THEN
            IF xrenda_mensal>=500.00 THEN
               IF (len(xuf)>=2 THEN
                   insert into cliente(nome,renda_mensal,uf) 
                       VALUES(xnome,xrenda_mensal,xuf);
               END IF;
            END IF;
        END IF;
END $$
```

Comment: Não é esse o rpoblema não, coloquei com o ';' e não resolveu.

Comment: na pergunta está com ';' `CREATE PROCEDURE sp_incluir_cliente(in xnome varchar(45), in 
xrenda_mensal decimal(10,2),in xuf varchar(2));`

Comment: @GabrielSilva: Não sei se você entendeu, mas é sem o ponto e virgula